# python for loop except

Tags: python

I have a list

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for my_value is my_list except'a':
    print(my_value)
```

Here I want to iterate over all values and print them excpet 'a'

How can I do this ? I know it can be done using if condition but I want to know if I can do it in one line if `for my_value in my_list except 'a'`

Comment: I've removed the django tag since "print" won't help you much in a web application. If it is django then print isn't correct.

Comment: I dont understand why people are running for downvote

Comment: Because there hasn't been any research effort involved. Searching for "python list except" returns results with the same code involved as Kasramvd's answer.

Answer (score 8):

It **can** be done in one line, although it's **horrible** programming style to do so.

```
for value in [ v for v in my_list if v != 'a' ]
```

What I'd recommend is two lines. `if ... : continue` immediately starts the next iteration of the loop, so the rest of the loop body is skipped.

```
for value in my_list:
   if value == 'a': continue 
   # rest of loop code
```

There's also an elegant one-liner that is not quite an answer to the problem posed. This is

```
for value in set(my_list) - {'a'}
```

The reasons it is not an answer are (a) that sets are un-ordered, so the for-loop doesn't necessarily process elements of my_list in the order that they are stored in my_list. And crucially (b), that a set cannot contain duplicates, so `set(['c','d','c'])` == `{'c','d'}` and the loop will process duplicates only once, not multiple times. Sometimes, that's a rather desirable consequence.

Comment: nonetheless, the 'elegant one-liner' solved my problem. +1 :)